# Windows proxy with R3.3.1

Tags: r, windows, proxy, rstudio, rgui

After updating from R R3.0.2 to R 3.3.1 it is not possible to connect to cran for package install over a proxy using Rgui.exe anymore. Same problem with RStudio.

```
HTTP status was '407 Proxy Authentication Required
```

I set the system environment variables `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` and controlled settings via `Sys.getenv("http_proxy")`. I also checked firewall settings. Has there anything changed between R3.0.2 and R3.3.1 which complicates the use of a proxy?

Answer (score 0):

My parallel installed R3.0.2 version correctly uses the proxy as defined in the `http_proxy` system variable whereas R3.3.1 doesn't. Finally I have found a workaround to update my packages also in R3.3.1 using `libcurl` in combination with the system environment variables http_proxy and https_proxy.

```
update.packages(ask='graphics',method="libcurl",checkBuilt=TRUE)
```